# Change gsettings for other (all) users remotelly

Tags: unity, launcher, gsettings

I configure several Ubuntu 12.04/13.10 computers remotely using cfengine3.  I am wondering how I can add an item to the Launcher for all users.  I am aware that I need to set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites, but I don't know how to do that for all users from a script.  I have also seen [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363754/how-can-i-set-default-applications-in-unity-launcher-for-other-users) which looks very similar to what I need, only I also want to **apply the changes to existing users**.  How can I do so?

To put it another way: I am wondering how to set launcher items for a (or all) users from a script running as root.

Answer (score 0):

**Remember that each user can have their own preferred applications.** That said, if CFengine allows you to run arbitrary commands you can make an script to edit `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.Unity.gschema.xml` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/73096/169736). Is recomended that for your script you use an XML library that interprets the XML files and allows you to edit them easily.

Comment: The question you linked to seems to imply this will only work for new users, not existing ones.  I am hoping to find a solution that will work for existing users.

Comment: @Daniel the problem is that existing users will already have a copy somewhere in their home directory which will override your system wide preferences.